# Create user-wide secrets Github

Tags: github, automation, github-actions

I am setting up Actions in  Github, some of them require a Token for authentication. This is the process I follow to generate them, which is [detailed in the Actions Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-using-an-action-inside-a-different-private-repository-than-the-workflow):

1. Go to my Account, generate a PAT
2. Go to the project and add a Secret using that PAT value
3. Add the variable name in the Action yml file, for example:

```
env:
  # used by semantic-release to authenticate at github and write to master
  # I used the developer tab to generate the token and then paste it to several projs
  # as a secret
  GH_TOKEN: ${{secrets.GH_TOKEN}}
  # used by semantic release to authenticate when publishing to npm
  # Generate it in NPM (you just need to be registered at npm which is simple)
  NPM_TOKEN: ${{secrets.NPM_TOKEN}}
```

Now, this is rather tedious, even having a single PAT, I'd still need to create a secret per project.

I have noticed though, that if you create an organization, you can create secrets at the ORG level.

Can you do something similar without having an organization? Can you create user secrets? Or maybe there is a way to  use the user settings in the Project's Action?

Comment: Don't think so. GitHub wants you to upgrade to an org ;-)

Comment: Thanks. Will do just for fun, there is the freeway @rethab